# Discord.py AttributeError: module 'cogs.admin' has no attribute 'setup'

Tags: python, бот, discord, discord.py, discord-api

Я делал бота и решил создать коги.
Однако после их создания я получил ошибку:

```
AttributeError: module 'cogs.admin' has no attribute 'setup'
```

Вот весь код

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import os

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='+')
client.remove_command('help')

for filename in os.listdir('./cogs'):
    if filename.endswith('.py'):
        client.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')

client.run('ТУТ ТОКЕН')
```

Файл-ког

```
import discord
from discord import Member
from discord.ext import commands

import random
import time

class example(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    # ТУТ КОМАНДЫ

def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(example(client))
```

Вот собственно и всё! Даже не понимаю, в чём ошибка...

Comment: Все думают, от ошибки достаточно строчки `AttributeError: module 'cogs.admin' has no attribute 'setup'` и становится сразу же все понятно? Интерпретатор обычно много строк печатает и они все одинаково полезны. Это повысит шанс на внятный ответ, или надо ждать исключительно хорошего спеца по когам (что это вообще) и дискорд-ботам.

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю вместо этого:

```
for filename in os.listdir('./cogs'):
    if filename.endswith('.py'):
        client.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')
```

Использовать это: `client.load_extension('Здесь путь к файлу')`

Пример: `client.load_extension('cogs.commands.moderation.command.muterole')`

Да и ошибку вам видал интерпритатор что в том файле нету этого:

```
def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(example(client))
```